# jQuery UI autocomplete triggered on field focus in Internet Explorer when there is an html 5 placeholder attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="item" value="" id="item" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter item name or scan barcode" accesskey="i"  />
```

Javascript:

```
    $( "#item" ).autocomplete({
        source: '<?php echo site_url("sales/item_search"); ?>',
        delay: 10,
        autoFocus: false,
        minLength: 0,
        select: function(event, ui)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $( "#item" ).val(ui.item.value);
            $('#add_item_form').ajaxSubmit({target: "#register_container", beforeSubmit: salesBeforeSubmit, success: itemScannedSuccess});
        }
    });

setTimeout(function(){$('#item').focus();}, 10);
```

When the page loads in Internet explorer the autocomplete occurs with an empty term value resulting in a bunch of results. If I remove the placeholder attribute, it functions as expected and does NOT make a request until typing occurs.

If I remove the focus event it also works in Internet Explorer. But I need to have the focus occur on page load, so this is not really an options. I would also like to keep the placeholder text.

The element functions as expected (no request until typing) in safari, firefox and chrome.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround so I can use placeholder attribute?

I have put together 2 examples; broken and fixed. The only difference between the 2 is the presence of the placeholder attribute (in the broken version).

The broken one only breaks in IE and functions as expected in other browsers.

NOTE: by broken I mean when focusing on field the autocomplete is activated when it shouldn't.

http://blastohosting.com/jquery_ui_autocomplete_bug/broken.html

http://blastohosting.com/jquery_ui_autocomplete_bug/working.html

NOTE: In both these examples the ajax will always be the same result. Please ignore this.

Comment: IE is the nightmare of every web developer. Another big bounty for a IE bug fix. :-) +1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue here is the way Internet Explorer handles the input event. 
The autocomplete menu is triggered on the input event of the input element (tags). 
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js Line 167

If you place this code before your setTimeout

```
document.getElementById('tags').addEventListener('input',function(ev){alert(ev.target.value);},false);
```

You will see that ie's native input event is fired on focus of the element. 
This doesn't happen on chrome. So it's likely not a bug with jquery, rather a feature of ie. As you stated in your question, this only happens when the input element has a placeholder attribute, without the attribute, the input event doesnt fire on focus.

I tried to add a `one` event handler for focus to call `preventDefault()` before triggering focus, but that still caused the input event to fire.

The autofocus html5 attribute also still caused the input event to fire.

I tried wrapping your code in a proper html/head/body but that had no effect

Lastly, as a workaround

1) I defaulted the minLength property to 1

```
minLength: 1
```

2) In the setTimeout I set the option for minLength to 0

```
$("#tags").focus().autocomplete("minLength", 0);
```

This seems to work on ie 9.

Comment: Thanks just doing minLength: 1 seemed to fix the problem!

Answer (score 1):

In

```
.autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    //minLength: 0,
    minLength: 1,
    source: $.proxy(this, "_source")                         
})`
```

works on checkboxes as Sumit answered. It probably works on textboxes as well.

But if you use autocomplete on textbox and dont want use minlength solution you can use alternatively

```
$("your element or class tag").autocomplete("instance").menu.active = false;
```

after textbox initialization jquery code.
I couldnt see how this statement can be used on checkbox as used on textbox, if u know i am gladly listen it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code helped me to fix this problem:

```
  $("your tag").autocomplete({
   source:bla-bla,
   open:function(e,ui) /*Hack for IE11*/
   {            
     $(this).focus();
   }
   })
   .one("focus",function(){/*Hack for IE11*/
     $(this).blur(); 
   });
```

Shortly, widget calls focus for your tag, for the tag we make one-trigger function which is called only 1 time for focus getting lost by calling blur.
Such a deceit for IE(bad IE).

Maybe there's a better solution. Please share it to this forum.

Comment: On IE 11, this solution makes me have to click the input twice for the first interaction with the input.

Answer (score 0):

here is my lazy initial way

```
elm.focus(function () {
    if(elm.autocomplete("instance")){
        elm.autocomplete(opts);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

place holder means something is display in textbox, And auto completed means when you write something in textbox then you will get auto complete result, now in your case you have already display something with the use to placeholder

First try to remove placeholder into you text box with **Backspace** and try it.

Comment: I understand what placeholder and autocomplete are. The problem is that in Internet Explorer if I set a placeholder attribute the autocomplete happens when I focus on the field with javascript. If I do NOT set the placeholder attribute, it doesn't autocomplete until typing (as expected)

Comment: check the place holder's string at page load time if it is true then don't work auto complete and when you key press autocomplete work.

Comment: See the two examples I posted above. I think this will explain the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Dear please refer this code

```
    $("#item").live("keydown.autocomplete",function(){
        put your code here. and try it 
        });
```

Comment: Live doesn't work in the version of query I am using. I fail to see how this will help. Can you provide a better example?