# Autocomplete - Want to hide cross (X) symbol on IE, for onkeyup event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Its very simple **UI** issues with **IE browsers**.

While searching on autocomplete, you get a cross sign on onkeyup event only on **IE versions**. And I want to hide it.

Whereas its not shown in other browsers like FF, chrome.

So it becomes difficult to inspect this cross element.

How do I hide it, or any idea about its id.

Comment: Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790121/jquery-ui-autocomplete-triggered-on-field-focus-in-internet-explorer-when-there

Answer (score 6):

The `-ms-clear` css rule can be used to hide the native clear symbol for the `input` element.

To clear use like below

```
input::-ms-clear {
   display: none;
 }
```

And also see the below links for specification.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-clear

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465740.aspx

Comment: Please don`t forget to mark it as answer if its useful.